# Stopover in Nadi, Fiji for 6 hours: Feasibility of popping into town on Easter Sunday?

Tags: public-holidays, stopovers, fiji

I'm flying from AKL (Auckland) to HNL (Honolulu) next month.  The flight stops in Fiji (Nadi) for 6.5 hours.

I realise it's tight, but I have a New Zealand passport and a desire to see as much of any country I visit, even if only a few hours.

If I am quick through customs and out the door, with transport options and the like, realistically how much time would I have in town, and given I arrive at 4pm on Easter Sunday, what would be open in Fiji on such a day?  Will the buses and/or taxis be running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [airport web site](http://airportsfiji.com/nadi_transit.php), since your connection is longer than 6 hours, they won't even let you hang out airside anyway.

> If your transit time exceeds six (6) hours, you will be required to
>   exit Immigration and Customs and enter Fiji

Might as well make a virtue of necessity. That website includes timetables for three bus lines that run to towns and resorts. Some of them seem to be as much as 2 hours from the airport, but there are stops closer as well. [The town of Nadi](http://www.fijime.com/index.php/fijime/page/19) is only 9 km from the airport, though it has no beaches.